# what tools can be used to debug python / django code on a remote hosts without graphical UI

Tags: python, django, vim

I started develop python / django code recently.
When I do it on my local machine (Ubuntu desktop), I use PyCharm, which I like a lot, because I can set up break points, and, when an exception occurs, it shows me the line in the code to which that exception relates.
Are there any tools available for python / django development in the environment without a graphic UI, which would give me break point and debugging features?
I know, that VIM with the right settings is an excellent coding tool, but I have no idea if it could be used for interactive debugging.

Comment: There's [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Comment: You might watch this, it has some interesting ideas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_QrK3fBkWg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use PyCharm, which I like a lot, because I can set up break points,
>   and, when an exception occurs, it shows me the line in the code to
>   which that exception relates.

Once you [configure it correctly](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/remote-debugging.html), PyCharm supports remote debugging so if you are happy with PyCharm keep using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice is developing locally, and use Pycharm "sync" to deploy the code from local to remote. If you prefer to code without GUI or in the console mode, you could try "emacs+jedi", it works well in the console mode. 
For debug, the best choice is pydev/pdb.

Comment: For me, an ideal combination would be using PyCharm and do remote debugging. Do not know if that is possible.

Comment: Yes, however, this remote debug requires your remote code and local code remain same,  and start the debugging server. you can refer to this article. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python-remote-debug-server.html

Answer (score 1):

import pdb and then place pdb.set_trace() where you want to start debugging. I find it to be the best tool for debugging Django apps. Use "n" to go to next line "s" to step into a function and "c" to continue. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html for more info.

You should also check out runserver plus and Werkzeug from https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions